# McAfee failing on update

Tags: updates, anti-virus

It seems like I'm experiencing some trouble when McAfee Anti-Virus tries to update. I get the error log listed below:

> Event Type: Error
>   Event Source: MsiInstaller
>   Event Category: None
>   Event ID: 11334
>   Date:  6/12/2012
>   Time:  10:16:39 AM
>   User:  CHICO\mjford
>
> Computer: F06127
>
> Description:
>
> Product: McAfee VirusScan Enterprise -- Error 1334.The file 'rc_strings.bin13' cannot be >
>
> installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file 'Cabs.w1.cab'. This could >
>
> indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this >
>
> package.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at >
>
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
>
> Data:
>
> 0000: 7b 31 34 37 42 43 45 30   {147BCE0
>
> 0008: 33 2d 43 30 46 31 2d 34   3-C0F1-4
>
> 0010: 43 39 46 2d 38 31 35 37   C9F-8157
>
> 0018: 2d 36 41 38 39 42 36 44   -6A89B6D
>
> 0020: 32 44 39 37 33 7d         2D973}

Any thoughts or tips?

Comment: It seems you are part of a domain?  Have you asked your IT Department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few things come to mind  which need to be working are;

1. *.cab file associations to permit extraction with explorer ( find a .cab file and test it)
2. "msiserver"  aka Windows Installer,  under Services near bottom needs to be running or start 
   on-demand..   run> net start msiserver with admin command window or as admin in run box.  It should take 5 seconds or less if it says starting up MSISERVER (MSI installer service) , which if it does means you may have fixed it for now.  ( run services.msc to see services)
3. mcAffee*.msi or self extrating exe to msi file  ACL's need to be enabled for trusted installer if running from server side script . If web download, ask McAffee
4. group Policy must not restrict msiserver from doing a windows installer service of 3rd party apps.

If I think of any more... I'll add

Tony